# Fetching Azure AD options from Database ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I have converted a ASP.NET MVC application to be multi-tenant and had to move the Azure AD credential data from the web.config file to database as the application is a distributed software. I am currently setting the connection name in the Session_Start event in Global.asax file based on the URL.

Is there a way that i can add my Database class as a transient in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs.

If that is not a good practice, what is the best way to configure Azure AD when the client-specific data is in the SQL DB?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your goals? Why do you need different credentials for a multi-tenant app? Why is the connection name being set per session?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When i say multi-tenant app, my current approach is to deploy a single site in IIS with multiple databases (one for each client) going forwards. I need different credentials, as the application is not currently hosted (which is the future plan) but is distributed, and we allow the clients to enter their Azure Credentials by creating a App registration specific to our app. And the connection name is based on the URL, so I am setting the DB connection name using Request.Headers["Host"] in Session_Start event in Global.asax.